# Comparing the contents of very large files efficiently

Tags: python, performance, file, io

I need to compare two files of differing formats quickly and I'm not sure how to do it. I would very much appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

I am working on CentOS 6 and I am most comfortable with Python (both Python 2 and Python 3 are available).

---

### The problem

I am looking to compare the contents two large files (quickly). The files, unfortunately, differ in content; I will need to modify the contents of one before I can compare them. They are not particularly well-organized, so I can't move linearly down each and compare line-by-line.

Here's an example of the files:

```
File 1                    File 2
Job,Time                  Job,Start,End
0123,3-00:00:00           0123,2016-01-01T00:00:00,2016-01-04T00:00:00
1111,05:30:00             1111,2016-01-01T00:00:00,2016-01-01T05:30:00
0000,00:00:05             9090.abc,2016-01-01T12:00:00,2016-01-01T22:00:00
9090.abc,10:00:00         0000,2015-06-01T00:00:00,2015-06-01T00:00:05
...                       ...
```

I would like to compare the contents of lines with the same "Job" field, like so:

```
Job        File 1 Content   File 2 Content
0123       3-00:00:00       2016-01-01T00:00:00,2016-01-04T00:00:00
1111       05:30:00         2016-01-01T00:00:00,2016-01-01T05:30:00
0000       00:00:05         2015-06-01T00:00:00,2015-06-01T00:00:05
9090.abc   10:00:00         2016-01-01T12:00:00,2016-01-01T22:00:00
...        ...              ...
```

I will be performing calculations on the *File 1 Content* and *File 2 Content* and comparing the two (for each line).

What is the most efficient way of doing this (matching lines)?

---

The system currently in place loops through one file in its entirety for each line in the other (until a match is found). This process may take hours to complete, and the files are always growing. I am looking to make the process of comparing them as efficient as possible, but even marginal improvements in performance can have a drastic effect.

I appreciate any and all help.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried reading both files at the same time one line at a time, and just comparing what you need like that ?

Comment: @MooingRawr Yes, of course. The contents of the files are not necessarily in the same order, however, so this won't work unless I pause on a line that doesn't have an obvious match and continue reading the other file. I'm not sure about the performance of such a script, but I would imagine it is comparable to the current system (though perhaps slightly faster, as it doesn't start at the beginning of the other file for each line).

Comment: So I'm guessing you have an unsorted text files? Which would be a headache to just compare those two together since you will have at worst O(n^2) time. I think your best bet is either sort the files (which will also take a take) which will speed up the compare, or slap them into an ordered storage database and then do your compares. I could be wrong tho.

Comment: @MooingRawr That is my conclusion at this point. I had hoped to make this user-friendly and portable (for multiple environments), but the files are simply too messy for this to be realistic. Luckily, the content is static and new information is appended to the end of the files, so I may opt for a system that saves the modified files for later use (along with date and time information) and updates it as the program is used, so only a few thousand lines will need to be modified instead of millions for typical use.

Comment: Is `Job` unique, or can there be multiple instances of rows with the same id and you need them all?

Comment: If the files are always growing, then whatever method you come up with will eventually fail, unless you find a way to stop the files from growing to infinity.

Comment: @roganjosh Yes, "Job" is unique; in theory, there should be one corresponding value in each file.

Comment: @rid They're log files for computer clusters. Growth will slow as hardware becomes obsolete or is replaced and as nodes are retired.

Comment: Ok cool. I think I have a slightly convoluted way of going about this but your current approach is disastrous in scaleability so it might be warranted. It's similar to the idea of Sohier and won't be beautiful code as that would take a long while to write, but should illustrate the idea.

Comment: Is ```9090.abc,2016-01-01T12:00:00,2016-01-01T22:00:00:00``` correct? There are three colons in the end time.

Comment: @wwii Ah, nice catch! You are correct, it's supposed to be `9090.abc,2016-01-01T12:00:00,2016-01-01T22:00:00`. I've edited my post to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

If you can find a way to take advantage of hash tables your task will change from O(N^2) to O(N). The implementation will depend on exactly how large your files are and whether or not you have duplicate job IDs in file 2. I'll assume you don't have any duplicates. If you can fit file 2 in memory, just load the thing into pandas with job as the index. If you can't fit file 2 in memory, you can at least build a dictionary of {Job #: row # in file 2}. Either way, finding a match should be substantially faster.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way I can think of is to use some standard UNIX tools which every modern Linux system should have. I know that this is not a python solution, but you determination to use python seems to build mostly on what you already know about that language and not any external constraints. Given how simple this task is using UNIX tools I will outline that solution here.

What you're trying to do is a standard database-style join where you look up information in two tables which share a column. For this the files must be sorted, but UNIX `sort` uses an efficient algorithm for that and you will not get around sorting or copying your file into a data structure which implies some sort of sorting.

Long version for demonstration

```
tail -n+2 file1.csv | LC_ALL=C sort -t , -k 1  > file1.sorted.csv
tail -n+2 file2.csv | LC_ALL=C sort -t , -k 1  > file2.sorted.csv
join -a 1 -a 2 -t , -1 1 -2 1 file1.sorted.csv file2.sorted.csv \
   > joined.csv
```

`tail -n+2` cuts off the first line of the file which contains the headers. `-t ,` parts are to set comma as columns separator, `-k 1` means sort on first column. `-1 1 -2 1` means "Use the first column of the first file and the first column of the second file as shared columns of the two files". `-a 1 -a 2` means "Also output lines from file 1 and file 2 for which no matching line can be found in the other file. This relates to a "full outer join" in database lingo. See [this SO question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120096/how-to-sort-big-files) and others for `LC_ALL=C`

If you want to avoid saving temporary files, you can sort on-the-fly using bash's "Process substitution" `<( ... )`

```
join -a 1 -a 2 -t , -1 1 -2 1 \
    <( tail -n+2 file1.csv | LC_ALL=C sort -t , -k 1 ) \
    <( tail -n+2 file2.csv | LC_ALL=C sort -t , -k 1 ) \
    > joined.csv
```

Note that `sort` supports multiple cores (see `--parallel` in `man sort`) If your files are so big that sorting the file on one machine takes longer than splitting it up, sending the chunks across the network, sorting them on multiple machines, sending them back and merging the sorted parts, refer to [this blog-post](https://blog.mafr.de/2010/05/23/sorting-large-files/).

Answer (score 1):

This is simple utility to convert File 2 format to  File 1 like format (i hope i understand question right, python 2 used)
save code to file `util1.py` for example

```
import time
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if  len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print 'Err need filename'
        sys.exit()
    with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
        line = f.next()
        for line in f:
            jb, start, end =  line.rstrip().split(',')
            dt_format ='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'
            start = time.strptime(start, dt_format)
            end = time.strptime(end, dt_format)
            delt = time.mktime(end) - time.mktime(start)
            m, s = divmod(delt, 60)
            h, m = divmod(m, 60)
            d, h = divmod(h, 24)
            if d !=0:
                print '{0},{1:d}-{2:02d}:{3:02d}:{4:02d}'.format(jb, int(d), int(h), int(m), int(s))
            else:
                print '{0},{2:02d}:{3:02d}:{4:02d}'.format(jb, int(d), int(h), int(m), int(s))
```

then run
`python ./util1.py f2.txt > f2-1.txt`
this save output to f2-1.txt

then

`cp f1.txt f1_.txt`

delete header row `Job,Start,End` from `f1_.txt`

`sort f1_.txt > f1.sorted.txt`

`sort f2-1.txt > f2-1.sorted.txt`

and 
`diff -u f1.sorted.txt f2-1.sorted.txt`

Comment: add some improvements, for readability. `9090.abc,2016-01-01T12:00:00,2016-01-01T22:00:00:00`  - has error ? or this record has msec ?

Comment: Yes, that's an error, sorry! The record does not have milliseconds. I've updated my post to reflect this. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to develop something where you'd split one of the files into smaller files (say 100,000 records each) and keep a pickled dictionary of each file that contains all `Job_id` as a key and its line as a value. In a sense, an index for each database and you could use a hash lookup on each subfile to determine whether you wanted to read its contents.

However, you say that the file grows continually and each `Job_id` is unique. So, I would bite the bullet and run your current analysis once. Have a line counter that records how many lines you analysed for each file and write to a file somewhere. Then in future, you can use `linecache` to know what line you want to start at for your next analysis in both `file1` and `file2`; all previous lines have been processed so there's absolutely no point in scanning the whole content of that file again, just start where you ended in the previous analysis.

If you run the analysis at sufficiently frequent intervals, who cares if it's O(n^2) since you're processing, say, 10 records at a time and appending it to your combined database. In other words, the first analysis takes a long time but each subsequent analysis gets quicker and eventually `n` should converge on `1` so it becomes irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Parse each file and convert the data to `datetime.timedelta` objects.  Make a dictionary with the job number as the keys and timedelta object as the value(s):

```
import operator, datetime, collections
def parse1(fp = 'job-file1.txt'):
    with open(fp) as f:
        next(f)
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            job, job_length = line.split(',',1)
            if '-' in job_length:
                days, time = job_length.split('-')
                hours, minutes, seconds = time.split(':')
            else:
                days = 0
                hours, minutes, seconds = job_length.split(':')
            job_length = datetime.timedelta(days = int(days),
                                            hours = int(hours),
                                            minutes = int(minutes),
                                            seconds = int(seconds))
            yield (job, job_length)

fmt = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'
def parse2(fp = 'job-file2.txt'):
    with open(fp) as f:
        next(f)
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            job, start, end = line.split(',')
            job_length = datetime.datetime.strptime(end, fmt) - datetime.datetime.strptime(start, fmt)
            yield (job, job_length)
```

Now you can either keep both timedelta objects and compare them later:

```
# {job_number:[timedelta1, timedelta2]
d = collections.defaultdict(list)

for key, value in parse1():
    d[key].append(value)

for key, value in parse2():
    d[key].append(value)
```

This lets you do something like:

```
differences = {job:lengths for job,lengths in d.items() if not operator.eq(*lengths)}
print(differences)
```

Or you can just keep the difference between file1 and file2 job lengths as the value

```
d = {key:value for key, value in parse1()}
for key, value in parse2():
    d[key] -= value
```

Then you would just check for differences with

```
[job for job, difference in d.items() if difference.total_seconds() != 0]
```